# dbt + jinja Cannot cast column value to int

Tags: sql, jinja2, amazon-redshift, dbt

I need Dynamic loop in dbt based on a column of the row

```
select id,loop_count,
{% set row_loop_cnt  %}
loop_count
{% endset %}
{% for i in range(loop_count) %}
    //creating a list 
{% endfor %}
created_list as column_name
from table_name
```

I am getting *'str object cannot be interpreted as an integer'*  error

I tried multiple way of casting like

`loop_count::int`       *'redshift'*

`loop_count | int`      *'Jinja'*

But no luck could you please help me here

Comment: Could you specify how do the values of `loop_count` look like, and what do you exactly need to do with those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros are compiled (templated) before the query is run. That means that the data in your database doesn't run through the jinja templater. When you `{% set row_loop_cnt = "loop_count"%}` you're just passing a string with the value `loop_count` into jinja, not the *data* from the field with that name.

From your query, I assume that the `table_name` table contains a field called `loop_count`, and that field's data includes an integer that you would like to use to repeat a value in another column.

In most databases, you can do this with SQL, and not involve jinja at all. It's possible to use the [`run_query` macro](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) to pull data into the jinja context, but this is slow and error-prone, and not really applicable in a situation where each row of your data wants to reference a different value.

Assuming the simplest possible implementation of `// creating a list`, I would write this query as:

```sql
select id, loop_count, repeat(value_col || ',', loop_count) as created_list
from table_name
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't explained actual logic requirement
I have column with value = abd,efg,hij,klm 
I need to loop through the comma separated string inside value and need to store in one column with some different arrangement 
 .can I get index inside repeat ?

Comment: can you edit your question to include an example of what your source data looks like and what you want the query to return?